# Why provider.nextFeature(feat) does not iterate over all layer features?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a point layer with over 1700 features, but iterating this way:

```
    i = 0

    while provider.nextFeature(feat):
        i =i + 1
        print '{0} de {1}: {2}'.format(i, provider.featureCount(), feat.id())
```

...I get only a few of them and no error arises.

Could it be possible to make a list of feature ids and then iterating over each QgsFeature by their id()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop is not recommended in such cases, use a for loop, it  is easier:

- a layer has n features -> layer.featureCount()
- a feature has an id -> feature.id(), a geometry and attributes

### with QGIS 1.8

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.select()
for feature in layer:
    geom = feature.geometry()
    attrs = feature.attributeMap()
    # the result is a dictionary
    for atr in attrs.values():
        print '{0} de {1}: {2}'.format(feature.id(), layer.featureCount(), atr.toString())
```

Result with one of my examples:

```
0 de 3: Aachen Formation
0 de 3: AAC
0 de 3: COU
0 de 3: 175
1 de 3: VAALS Formation
1 de 3: VAA
1 de 3: COU
1 de 3: 185
....
```

### with QGIS 2.0

```
 layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
 for feature in layer.getFeatures():
     geom = feature.geometry()
     attrs = feature.attributes()
     # the result is a list
     for elem in attrs:
         print '{0} de {1}: {2}'.format(feature.id(), layer.featureCount(), elem)
```

and with a dictionary, you can access the field names:

```
fields = layer.pendingFields()
# name of the fields
field_names = [field.name() for field in fields] 
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    atr = dict(zip(field_names, feature.attributes()))
    print atr
```

Result

```
{u'FORM': u'AAC', u'DESCRIPTIO': u"Aachen Formation", u'CLASSE': u'COU',u'SYMBOL': 175.0}
{u'FORM': u'AAC',  u'DESCRIPTIO': u"Vaals Formation", u'CLASSE': u'COU', u'SYMBOL': 185.0}
```

....